# How to use a class from MS-COCO and add 2 new classes with Mask RCNN?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, mscoco

I want my model to detect only 3 classes i.e. Person, Tyre and Road. I'm using the pretrained MS COCO weights which are already trained on the 'Person' class.

How do I use this already present 'Person' class and further train my model for 2 new classes i.e 'Tyre' and 'Road'?

I've set `NUM_CLASSES = 1 + 3` (background + objects).

My dataset however only has annotations for 'Tyre' and 'Road' and hence these are the only classes I'm adding using `self.add_class(source_name, class_id, class_name)`.

Comment: It will be helpful to answer if you can give more details on how you are training your model. Like what framework you use.

Comment: @55597 I'm basically working over the 'balloons.py' example located here https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/tree/master/samples/balloon, since they only had to use 1 class i.e. 'balloon' they added it using `self.add_class` method. However, I'm adding 2 new classes using this but have no clue how to use the 'Person' class

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am also looking for the answer.